# Firebase: How to stop listening to snapshot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, listener, google-cloud-firestore

I have a javascript application that uses the onSnapshot listener to listen to changes in my firebase collection. The docs tell me to unsubscribe when I am no longer in need of the listener. In React I would do this in `componentWillUnmount()` but if I've set up the listener in a vanilla class (not React), how would I unsubscribe in this situation?

How I'm implementing it...

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.presenter = new MyPresenter();
  }
  ...rest of component

class MyPresenter {
    constructor() {
      const listener = db.collection("cities")
        .onSnapshot(function () {});
    }
}
```

Comment: You stop listening when you no longer require the updates.  It's impossible to know when that should be, given the information so far.  You'll have to figure that out.

Comment: @DougStevenson i've updated my question to be clearer

Comment: You call this constructor in a certain spot in your app's lifecycle. You should call `unsubscribe()` in the opposing spot in its lifecycle. Sorry to be vague, but that's the best I can say right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that you'd just want to make a method on `MyPresenter` called "stop()" or something similar, which does the unsubscribe.  Then, in your component, call `presenter.stop()` during its `componentWillUnmount()`.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense. 
To add another question just to wrap my head around this. Quoting the docs ` This allows the client to stop using bandwidth to receive updates. `. If I don't ever call the unsubscribe at what point will the client stop receiving updates? When my tab is closed I'm assuming?

Comment: If you don't stop listening, then your app will continue to receive updates for as long as it remains open.  If you close the tab or refresh the page, all context is lost, and you'd have to listen again to get updates.